# Escaping '.' character in string

Tags: go

I am trying to escape all occurrence of '.' character in a string with backslash. When I run my Go code it works fine but when I compile and build the binary and then run it, it adds one more backslash.

```
s := "strings.test"
i := strings.Replace(s, ".", "\\.", -1)
```

I even tried

```
s := "strings.test"
i := strings.Replace(s, ".", `\.`, -1)
```

**Output: "strings\\.test"**

**Expected Output: "strings\.test"**

Not sure what is the difference between running the main.go vs building the project and then running it.

Comment: The output should be same and is same for both building and running the file..The output you are saying should be when you chose new string as `\\\\.`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your output? This Go Playground gives me your desired output https://play.golang.org/p/fGzLeE_3h6h

Compiling does the same, I get the correct output... Are you sure your code is running fine (with the values you expect)?

`go run` does the same as  `go build` however `go run` executes the compiled binary for you, more like a shortcut

Comment: Yeah, that's what is strange about this. One thing, I am running in my mac but build and test is run on a RHEL server. Could this issue be because of OS?